# confusion in th and tr tags functionality

Tags: html, css

I've the below code in my html table.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="right" colspan="4">
                <span class="font-style-bold">SCHEDULE OF RATES</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                </div>
            </th>
            <th class="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                </div>
            </th>
            <th class="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                    <span class="font-style-bold">Unit</span>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th class="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                    <span class="font-style-bold">Rate $</span>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                    <span class="font-style-boldunderline">ROOFER</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="align-left">
                <div class="para">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</tbody>
```

here is the css

```
  .frame-all thead th {
margin-top: 0em;
padding-left: 0.2em;
padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}
```

when i run this i get the below screen.

[image]

when i change the `th` to `td`, i'm getting the below screen(which is what i want). just want to know why the difference and, can't this case be possible with `th`

[image]

Comment: Your CSS would be useful, please :)

Comment: any `CSS` assigned to `th`?

Comment: Hi NiettheDarkAbsol and Rien: thanks for reminding me about css, i've updated my question with the css used thanks again :)

Comment: Your code doesn't match the images posted, nor will that newly posted css make the code render like the images. Can I suggest you create two jsfiddles, to illustrate your problem.

Comment: There may only be one `<thead>` for the table. use `<caption>` for the first description of the table

Comment: @AlexThomas, now it does. Thanks

Comment: @user2423959 there's so many things wrong with this code. You need to clean it up first before you can begin to get the desired layout.

Comment: You have one nested tbody and two theads, this is so confusing. You should put one thead and one tbody (not a nested one).

Comment: You need to pass this through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org). `rowspan="align-left">`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be only one thead and tbody in a table. Both should be direct children of the `<table>` tag.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="right" colspan="4">
        <span class="font-style-bold">SCHEDULE OF RATES</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="align-left">
        <div class="para">
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="align-left">
        <div class="para">
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="align-left">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-bold">Unit</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="align-left">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-bold">Rate $</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="align-left">
        <div class="para">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="align-left">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="font-style-boldunderline">ROOFER</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="align-left">
        <div class="para">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="align-left">
        <div class="para">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```